# Setup two NICs, one public and one private

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, ip, nic

I have two servers in a datacenter, both running Windows Server 2008 R2. Both of these servers have 2 NICs. I am trying to setup one NIC to be used for public access and the other for a private network between the two servers (I have been assigned 2 private IP addresses by the datacenter).

I setup the first NIC (public) fine. I then setup the second but I'm being warned that I have 2 default gateways and this will cause serious problems. I ignored this message and continued, but the server now can't connect to the public network.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should empty the gateway setting on the private NIC if you are still able to control the server or ask someone who can do this if you lost control over it. You can try to reach the first server from another one by its private IP if you still have control over the second server.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was never completely locked out as I had KVMoIP.